# How to delete foreign key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried both the syntaxes:

```
Alter Table bc DROP FOREIGN KEY STUD_ID;
```

It is giving the error: Can't DROP 'STUD_ID'; check that column/key exists

```
Alter Table bc DROP CONSTRAINT STUD_ID;
```

It is giving the error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT STUD_ID' at line 1

Suggest me the possible ways.

Comment: First query is ok. Your key has probably another name than the column it indexes. Run `show index from bc`

Comment: Hi, I don't see any problem in the first query. Can you please upload your table here?

Comment: @juergend It's done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP FOREIGN KEY ForeignKeyConstraintName;
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first query works. It is telling you that there is no such key to drop. This means your key has another name. It has not the same name as the column it indexes. Run

```
show index from bc
```

to show all key names and then run your query again with the correct name

```
Alter Table bc DROP FOREIGN KEY <STUD_ID_index_name>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
alter table bc drop foreign key forconstraintname
```

Comment: Even my comment contains more info than that.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.